# Upload a file with a comma in its name with curl

Tags: curl, upload, escape-characters, escaping

How can I upload a file named `yes, this filename has a comma.txt` with the cli `curl`?

You would normally do this to upload a file with `curl`:

```
curl --progress-bar -F "fileUpload=@filename.txt"
```

However `curl` interprets commas as multiple files to upload, so this will not work:

```
curl --progress-bar -F "fileUpload=@yes, this filename has a comma.txt"
```

How can I escape the filename?

---

I already found a workaround by creating a temporary symlink to the original file and pass that to curl. However the problem is that the filename that `curl` sends to the server is the filename of the symlink, not the original file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have not said what OS you are using. The following solutions work for Linux (not only for `curl` but most kinds of [escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)):

- Put the file name in quotes (you need to escape them as well):

  ```
    curl --progress-bar -F "fileUpload=@\"yes, this filename has a comma.txt\""
  ```
- Escape the comma

  ```
    curl --progress-bar -F "fileUpload=@yes\, this filename has a comma.txt"
  ```

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.2, only the quoting worked. The one where the comma is escaped, tries to upload a file called "yes" (`curl: (26) couldn't open file "yes\"`).

Comment: On Mac OSX 10.9.4, I had to put the quotes after the `@` like so: `curl --progress-bar -F "fileUpload=@\"yes, this filename has a comma.txt\""`

Comment: Had same problem as spyle on Ubuntu 14.04.  Terdon's answer actually sends the literal filename instead of the contents of the file.

Comment: @CoryR.King yes, of course, that's intentional. How else would it work? To send the file's contents, you would need to specify a remote file name to write to.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. The apk file has spaces in it.

```
#!/bin/bash
 
API_TOKEN="____"

ARTIFACT_PATH=$(find $2 -name *.ipa -o -name *.apk)

curl https://upload.diawi.com/ \
-F token=${API_TOKEN} \
-F file=@"${ARTIFACT_PATH}" \
-F callback_emails='example@gmail.com'
```